# PyEphem - Error next_pass()

Tags: python, tracking, pyephem, satellite

trying to calculate is the time that a satellite rises above the horizon of an observer (TO), the time the satellite reaches the maximum elevation above the horizon (TCA) and the time a satellite passes below the observer's horizon (LOS) in a day(2013/06/01), I found a mistake in one passing

```
import ephem
import math

line1 = "ISS (ZARYA)"
line2 = "1 25544U 98067A   13150.58028350  .00009895  00000-0  16910-3 0  9060"
line3 = "2 25544 051.6474 195.6448 0009976 014.6542 345.5254 15.50593990236071"
iss = ephem.readtle(line1, line2, line3)

campos = ephem.Observer()
campos.lon,campos.lat,campos.elevation = '-41:30.00','-21:75.00', 0 

campos.date = '2013/6/1'
fim = campos.date+1

print """Date/Time (UTC)       Alt/Azim   Lat/Long  Elev"""
print """====================================================="""
while  campos.date < fim:

   info = campos.next_pass(iss) 
   print info
   for p in range(0,6,2):

      campos.date = info[p]   
      iss.compute(campos)
      print "%s | %4.1f %5.1f | %4.1f %+6.1f | %5.1f" % \
    (info[p], math.degrees(iss.alt), math.degrees(iss.az), 
     math.degrees(iss.sublat), math.degrees(iss.sublong),iss.elevation/1000.)
   print " "
```

output:

Date/Time (UTC)       Alt/Azim     Lat/Long  Elev
   =====================================================
   (2013/6/1 10:01:51, 31:57:07.9, 2013/6/1 10:04:21, 1:57:44.6, 2013/6/1 10:06:52, 86:00:15.8)
    2013/6/1 10:01:51 |  0.0  32.0 | -4.2  -30.7 | 422.7
    2013/6/1 10:04:21 |  2.0  59.1 | -11.8  -25.1 | 423.7
    2013/6/1 10:06:52 | -0.0  86.0 | -19.2  -19.3 | 424.5

```
(2013/6/1 11:34:59, 323:43:50.2, 2013/6/1 11:40:35, 76:09:23.5, 2013/6/1 11:46:11, 138:14:56.1)
 2013/6/1 11:34:59 |  0.2 323.7 | -5.2  -53.5 | 422.8
 2013/6/1 11:40:35 | 76.2  68.9 | -21.8  -40.6 | 424.7
 2013/6/1 11:46:11 |  0.0 138.2 | -36.9  -24.1 | 424.9

 (2013/6/1 13:13:25, 266:18:49.6, 2013/6/1 11:43:23, 13:48:06.0, 2013/6/1 11:46:14, 138:15:55.2)
 2013/6/1 13:13:25 |  0.0 266.3 | -21.9  -64.1 | 424.7
 2013/6/1 11:43:23 | 13.8 136.3 | -29.7  -33.0 | 425.0
 2013/6/1 11:46:14 | -0.2 138.3 | -37.0  -23.9 | 424.9

 (2013/6/1 13:13:25, 266:18:50.8, 2013/6/1 13:17:32, 6:57:09.7, 2013/6/1 13:21:40, 171:25:48.7)
 2013/6/1 13:13:25 |  0.0 266.3 | -21.9  -64.1 | 424.7
 2013/6/1 13:17:32 |  7.0 218.6 | -33.2  -52.4 | 425.0
 2013/6/1 13:21:40 |  0.0 171.4 | -42.9  -37.3 | 424.5

 (2013/6/1 19:48:36, 195:26:26.5, 2013/6/1 12:42:57, -62:57:07.1, 2013/6/1 13:21:39, 171:33:53.8)
 2013/6/1 19:48:36 |  0.0 195.4 | -42.2  -48.9 | 418.2
 2013/6/1 12:42:57 | -63.0 318.8 | 51.6 -164.5 | 405.3
 2013/6/1 13:21:39 |  0.0 171.6 | -42.9  -37.4 | 424.5

(2013/6/1 19:48:36, 195:27:10.8, 2013/6/1 12:42:57, -62:57:11.0, 2013/6/1 13:21:39, 171:33:31.1)
2013/6/1 19:48:36 |  0.0 195.5 | -42.2  -48.9 | 418.2
2013/6/1 12:42:57 | -63.0 318.8 | 51.6 -164.5 | 405.3
2013/6/1 13:21:39 |  0.0 171.6 | -42.9  -37.4 | 424.5

(2013/6/1 19:48:36, 195:27:08.8, 2013/6/1 12:42:57, -62:57:10.9, 2013/6/1 13:21:39, 171:33:32.1)
2013/6/1 19:48:36 |  0.0 195.5 | -42.2  -48.9 | 418.2
2013/6/1 12:42:57 | -63.0 318.8 | 51.6 -164.5 | 405.3
2013/6/1 13:21:39 |  0.0 171.6 | -42.9  -37.4 | 424.5

(2013/6/1 19:48:36, 195:27:08.9, 2013/6/1 12:42:57, -62:57:10.9, 2013/6/1 13:21:39,  171:33:32.0)
2013/6/1 19:48:36 |  0.0 195.5 | -42.2  -48.9 | 418.2
2013/6/1 12:42:57 | -63.0 318.8 | 51.6 -164.5 | 405.3
2013/6/1 13:21:39 |  0.0 171.6 | -42.9  -37.4 | 424.5

(2013/6/1 19:48:36, 195:27:08.9, 2013/6/1 12:42:57, -62:57:10.9, 2013/6/1 13:21:39, 171:33:32.0)
2013/6/1 19:48:36 |  0.0 195.5 | -42.2  -48.9 | 418.2
2013/6/1 12:42:57 | -63.0 318.8 | 51.6 -164.5 | 405.3
2013/6/1 13:21:39 |  0.0 171.6 | -42.9  -37.4 | 424.5
```

.....

Where am I wrong?